# PHP in post content

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to Wordpress and I'm a bit stuck.

I have created a site and I'm linking to Amazon. I read their ToS and I'm not allowed to hardcode the price in because of price fluctuations. I signed up to the API and got my key and have programmed a function to query the API for the price of an item using the ASIN. This works fine, but when I try to use it in a post it doesn't work.

I downloaded the "Insert PHP" plugin so I can use shortcode to call my function and echo out the price.

This works partially, but when I echo the returned string it's wrapped in `<p>` tags so I cannot echo it out in a `<h2>` tag properly.

How can I get this to work? Is there a way I can echo it out without being wrapped in the `<p>` tags?

Thanks

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: `<?php echo "item price"; ?>`  Is all I was using essentially but the "Insert PHP" plugin seems to wrap it in `<p>` tags, but I found out after a bit of research, the way I should do it, is create a shortcode of my own for my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a stupid question, I just realized, if I just create a custom shortcode for it, the plugin will not wrap it in `<p>` tags then, or even better still just create it as a plugin of it's own.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you considered using a plugin for the whole integration?](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-amazon-affiliates-wordpress-plugin/3057503) Not sure if you're doing something more customized than affiliate products though.